# How to get content of div without JavaScript script blocks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following HTML

```
<div id="example">
...some text...
<script type="text/javascript">
... some javascript...
</script>
</div>
```

How to get content of `#example` but also without the JavaScript tags or JavaScript code?

Comment: Why are you putting the JS there?  Put it at the top or bottom of the HTML source, it doesn't really matter where it sits(people will tell you it should be either all in the `head` tag or all just before `/body` but I don't see why it would matter either way.

Comment: I think they say to put it before the end of the body. so if you have a huge bit of code the page loads first.  Also if you're referencing something it needs to be on the page before the script referencing it.

Comment: Hi Pandit, you must have your reasons of placing the script tag where it is (if not, you should definitely move it like Andrew says). I would be helpful however to share some code which you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

And to answer the general question, if you need to get the contents of a node with some of the children not included, you probably need to remove the tags you don't want in there, in your case the script tags.

If you need to keep the original intact, take a look at cloneNode (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) on how to get a clone of the node that you can work on without touching the original.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to grab the text that's inside the `id="example"`, you could just use:

```
var getExample = document.getElementById('example').innerHTML;
```

or with `jQuery`:

```
var $getExample = $('#example').html();
```

I'm assuming you just didn't want the `JavaScript` inside the `id="example"` div, being as you tagged this `JavaScript`. In that case you could create a `JavaScript` file and add it with

```
<script src="javascriptFileName.js"></script>
```

this would be placed at the bottom of the body.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can try this way. See here http://jsfiddle.net/AnjJa/129/

```
var el = $('#example').clone();
el.find('script').remove();
alert(el.html());
```

But why you put the JS there?